# In a Leaflet Map, how to make the popup scroll between different markers at the exact same coordinates?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Currently, I have about 20 markers being shown in the same coordinate, as the data given. I have made popups for all of them containing their data. However, when I click them, it shows only the details of the top marker.

Is there a way to have the popup with a side arrow which allows the next data point to show up?

Comment: Use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: For a quick and great UX solution, I definitely agree with @GrzegorzT. - use leaflet markercluster.  If you want the specific UX behavior you describe with popups you can toggle through with left and right arrows, which is exactly what the ArcGIS JS API does, you'll likely need to build that yourself from scratch.  Drop a comment or edit the question if that's the case.